# Simple Python Battleship game

Tags: python

I recently started learning python and decided to try and make my first project. I'm trying to make a battleship game that randomly places two 3 block long ships on a board. But it doesn't work quite right. I made a while loop for ship #2 that's supposed to check and see if two spaces next to it are free, then build itself there. But sometimes it just slaps itself on top of where ship #1 already is. can someone help me out?

**Here's the first part of the code:**

```
from random import randint

###board:

board = []

for x in range(7):
    board.append(["O"] * 7)

def print_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print " ".join(row)

###ships' positions:
#ship 1
def random_row(board):
    return randint(0, len(board) - 1)
def random_col(board):
    return randint(0, len(board[0]) - 1)
row_1 = random_row(board)
col_1 = random_col(board)

#ship 2
row_2 = random_row(board)
col_2 = random_col(board)
def make_it_different(r,c):
    while r == row_1 and c == col_1:
        r = random_row(board)
        c = random_col(board)
        row_2 = r
        col_2 = c
make_it_different(row_2,col_2)


### Makes the next two blocks of the ships:
def random_dir():
    n = randint(1,4)
    if n == 1:
        return "up"
    elif n == 2:
        return "right"
    elif n == 3:
        return "down"
    elif n == 4:
        return "left"
#ship one:
while True:
    d = random_dir() #reset direction
    if d == "up":
        if row_1 >= 2:
            #building...
            row_1_2 = row_1 - 1
            col_1_2 = col_1
            row_1_3 = row_1 - 2
            col_1_3 = col_1
            break
    if d == "right":
        if col_1 <= len(board[0])-3:
            #building...
            row_1_2 = row_1
            col_1_2 = col_1 + 1
            row_1_3 = row_1
            col_1_3 = col_1 + 2
            break
    if d == "down":
        if row_1 <= len(board)-3:
            #building...
            row_1_2 = row_1 + 1
            col_1_2 = col_1
            row_1_3 = row_1 + 2
            col_1_3 = col_1
            break
    if d == "left":
        if col_1 >= 2:
            #building...
            row_1_2 = row_1
            col_1_2 = col_1 - 1
            row_1_3 = row_1
            col_1_3 = col_1 - 2
            break
ship_1 = [(row_1,col_1),(row_1_2,col_1_2),(row_1_3,col_1_3)]
```

**And here's where the ship 2 part is:**

```
#ship two:
while True:
    d = random_dir() #reset direction
    if d == "up":
        if row_2 >= 2:
            if (row_2 - 1,col_2) not in ship_1 and (row_2 - 2,col_2) not in ship_1:
                #building...
                row_2_2 = row_2 - 1
                col_2_2 = col_2
                row_2_3 = row_2 - 2
                col_2_3 = col_2
                break
    if d == "right":
        if col_2 <= len(board[0])-3:
             if (row_2 ,col_2 + 1) not in ship_1 and (row_2,col_2 + 2) not in ship_1:
                #building...
                row_2_2 = row_2
                col_2_2 = col_2 + 1
                row_2_3 = row_2
                col_2_3 = col_2 + 2
                break
    if d == "down":
        if row_2 <= len(board)-3:
            if (row_2 + 1 ,col_2) not in ship_1 and (row_2 + 2,col_2) not in ship_1:
                #building...
                row_2_2 = row_2 + 1
                col_2_2 = col_2
                row_2_3 = row_2 + 2
                col_2_3 = col_2
                break
    if d == "left":
        if col_2 >= 2:
            if (row_2 ,col_2 - 1) not in ship_1 and (row_2,col_2 - 2) not in ship_1:
                #building...
                row_2_2 = row_2
                col_2_2 = col_2 - 1
                row_2_3 = row_2
                col_2_3 = col_2 - 2
                break

###test
board[row_1][col_1] = "X"
board[row_1_2][col_1_2] = "X"
board[row_1_3][col_1_3] = "X"
board[row_2][col_2] = "Y"
board[row_2_2][col_2_2] = "Y"
board[row_2_3][col_2_3] = "Y"
#Ship1 = X's and Ship2 = Y's
print_board(board)
```

Comment: It doesn't look like make_it_different is doing anything. Throw a return at the end of the function and then try this instead `row_2, col_2 = make_it_different(row_2,col_2)`. When you set a variable inside of a function you're not setting it on a global scale (unless you want to use the global row_2 and col_2 vars in the function which I don't suggest)

Comment: I'd recommend choosing the orientation of the ship before its position.

Comment: Quick python tip: you can use list comprehension to create lists eg. `board=[["O"]*WIDTH for i in range(HEIGHT)]` where I moved the magic 7's to variables for readability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend allowing your placing code to run through simply and without if statements, it will be much cleaner.  Then, at the end, you can check to see if any of the pieces overlap, and if they do reset.

Depending on how you end up deciding to store the points that the individual ships lie in, maybe a list of tuples. You could do this

the place ship method could return a list of tuples (points)

```
def placeShip():
    points = []

    # put random point generation here

    for point in points:
        if point in otherShipPoints:
            return placeShip()         # overlap detected, redo ship placement

    return points
```

Put your placement code in a single function so that it can be called this way simply.  Your code is starting to get messy and I recommend going to an approach like this to keep from running into spaghetti code problems.

You could also give `placeShip()` a parameter for the size of ship you want to add, then this method could be your all-in-one ship placer.  Just make your function look like this `placeShip(size)` and then randomly generate that many points within your grid

Comment: What happens if placeShip() yields a bad placement when you've just finished your loop?

Comment: Ahh sorry, it didn't look like it was going to be recursive before your edit. This looks better, +1

Comment: does this placeShip function apply to the initial point created, the additional two I add on later, or maybe both things at once?

Comment: It depends on you implement this function.  This is pseudocode, you can change it how you want.  I'd recommend doing it for *all* ships

Comment: @user2631796 I can elaborate further if you'd like to come to chat

Comment: actually I just got done implementing it. It works great now. I didn't know there was any kind of chat on this site. I'll come to chat if you're interested in seeing the new code. :)

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/34553/mads-chat?tab=general @user2631796

Comment: Hey Stephan, are you still interested in helping me finish this battleship game?

Comment: @Nathan sure, but I'm extremely busy today, i could only answer quick questions until later this weekend

Answer (score 2):

Assigning to `row_2` and `col_2` in `make_it_different` doesn't assign to the global variables by those names. Python's rule for determining a function's local variables is that anything a function assigns to without a `global` declaration is local; assigning to `row_2` and `col_2` creates new local variables instead of changing the globals. You could fix this by declaring `row_` and `col_2` `global`, but it'd probably be better to instead pass the new values to the caller and let the caller assign them.

(Why does `make_it_different` take initial values of `row_2` and `col_2` at all? Why not just have it generate coordinates until if finds some that work?)

Comment: you lost me on that last part. What do you mean make it generate coordinates, Isn't that what it does? How would I do it without the two values? Could you give me an example?

Comment: @user2631796: It doesn't actually need to take initial values and make them different if they don't work; it can just generate values until it gets values that work.

Answer (score 2):

You are writing a lot of code for this, maybe another approach would be better.  Try writing a function like

```
def ship_points(rowcol = (3,3), shiplength = 4, direction = (1,0), boardsize=(7,7)):
    points = []
    for i in xrange(shiplength):
        points.append((rowcol[0]+i*direction[0], rowcol[1]+i*direction[1]))
        if points[i][0] >= boardsize[0] or points[i][1] >= boardsize[1]:
            return None
    return points
```

Now you can just generate points for each ship and check for identical points directly.  Much less code, and way more reusable.